# on bind an input field that was generated using a ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-on

I am wanting to bind a input field that is generated into the page using ajax.

I have tried a number of different jQuery codes and none of them give any type of success.

Here are the codes I have used:

```
$('#bookingcoupon').bind('input', function(){});
$(document).on('bind', '#bookingcoupon', function(){});
$('body').on('bind', '#bookingcoupon', function(){});
$('.divname').on('bind', '#bookingcoupon', function(){});
```

None of which works

When I use a click listener using:

```
 $('.divwrapper').on('click', '.clickbutton', function(){});
```

This works fine, it just does not like the bind version of the on() function.

Any advise would be appriciated :)

Comment: You should be using `on()`, so the code you're using is the correct method. `bind()` was deprecated a long time ago and should not be used, and there is no `bind` event.

Comment: Yes, as per above comment `on()` should be used. Little correction in below codes:`$(document).on('bind', '#bookingcoupon', function(){});
$('body').on('bind', '#bookingcoupon', function(){});
$('.divname').on('bind', '#bookingcoupon', function(){});`. Here #bookingcoupon will select only first element having id as bookingcoupon, whereas if you used '[id="bookingcoupon"]' then it will select all elements having id as 'bookingcoupon'.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan as you can see, I have been using the on function. It does not work

Comment: Your question literally says 'This works fine'...? Are you saying it's not working? If so, we need to see a complete example of the problem, including the HTML, and a much more clear description of what you're expecting to happen

Comment: @PrasadWargad I have tried the on() function and my first thought was on but then I tried bind because I could not get on to work.

I used only the id name because there is only 1 element that is generated with that ID else I would have done the input[id=idname] :)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan it says None of which works. The only thing that works is the on('click') which I said at the end with the caption, only the bind version of the on() does not work.

Sorry Miss said the bind function rather than bind version of the on()

Comment: Read your second from last line. It says using `on()` works, which is correct. The reason none of your previous methods work is because they're invalid. As I said in my previous comment, `bind()` is deprecated and there is no `bind` event.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yes, mis-spelt which I replied in last comment. Sorry

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan there is no on('bind'); any longer? not what the on() function says in the jQuery documents page: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan if the bind has been removed, how do you bind in jQuery now?

Comment: Using `on()`... this why I'm so confused as to what your problem is, given that what you've shown works.,

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan $(document).on('bind', '#bookingcoupon', function(){}); doesnt work, only the on('click') works and not the on('bind')

Comment: There never was an `on('bind')` and the documentation clearly make no mention of it. I think you're confusing yourself here.

Comment: AGAIN, THERE IS NO `on('bind')`. `bind` is not an event. Use an actual event name like the documentation, that you yourself linked to, explains.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan then I asked what do you use instead of bind, and you said your confused because I said it works

Comment: No I said to use `on()`, with an actual recognised event, as you are in the question, and as the documentation explains.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan sorry, so confusing typing instead of talking lol... So basically the whole BIND has been removed, so do I need to use something like keypress, focus or something within them lines?

Answer (score 0):

I made this example, maybe it can help you:

http://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/873462/

```
// find elements
var button = $("button")

// handle click and add class
button.on("click", function(){
  $("#append").append( "<input class='sameClass' type='text'></input></br>" );

  $('.sameClass').change(function(){
    $('.sameClass').bind('change',functionChange(this));
  });

});

function functionChange(obj){
    alert($(obj).val());
};
```

And the HTML:

```
<div id="banner-message">
  <button >Add TextBox</button>
  <div id="append">
  </div>
</div>
```